# How to successfully UNION ALL for double precision in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, union

I am encountering a really strange problem.

This query does not work:

```
SELECT
       t1.status :: TEXT,
       t1.total_amount :: float AS amount

FROM accounting.payment_in_records AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
       t1.fees :: float          AS amount,
       'Processed' :: TEXT       AS status
FROM accounting.payment_out_record_detail_groups AS t1
WHERE t1.fees > 0;
```

Error:

```
[42804] ERROR: UNION types text and double precision cannot be matched Position: 147
```

But this query works:

```
SELECT
       t1.total_amount :: float AS amount,
       t1.status :: TEXT
FROM accounting.payment_in_records AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
       t1.fees :: float          AS amount,
       'Processed' :: TEXT       AS status
FROM accounting.payment_out_record_detail_groups AS t1
WHERE t1.fees > 0;
```

So the column order must be the same?

Comment: Is that your real query? I cannot see a position 2767 there...

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to simplify the question. I posted the real query, hopefully its not too much

Comment: Does it work with parentheses like this: `(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...)`?

Comment: No, still the same error

Comment: Hmmm. I don't see the problem right away. Try to reduce the example by removing everything that you can so that the error *remains*. Maybe then we can see clearer.

Comment: I will do that, but it just strange that removing those lines make the query run so the problem should be that line right?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe hello I just discover new behavior, maybe you can see it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the order must be the same. It is not the column *alias*, but the column *position* that is the deciding factor.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html) for details about “`UNION` compatible data types”.

The documentation has

> The resolution algorithm is applied separately to each output column of a union query.

It fails to make explicit that a column is identified by its position.